# Different selectors, same style, how to prevent duplicate output in less

Tags: css, less

I have the following less code, and it causes four code blocks to be generated, with three blocks having the same content.

Is there a way to ensure only two code blocks will be generated without having to use long chained selectors separated by comma for these elements?

```
section.bmform {
    .thanks-for-requesting {
        .change-request {
            .highlight_bordered();
        }
    }
    .bmform-submit-container {
        .bmform_submit {
            .highlight_bordered();
        }
    }
    .btn {
        &.btn-danger {
            &.plus, 
            &.minus {
                .highlight_bordered();
            }
        }
    }
}
.highlight_bordered() {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #af2222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 4px 6px 2px 6px;
    &:hover {
        border: 2px solid #8c2828;
        background-color: #bf0808;
    }
}
```

The above generates the following code:

```css
section.bmform .thanks-for-requesting .change-request {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 2px solid #af2222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 4px 6px 2px
}
section.bmform .bmform-submit-container .bmform_submit {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 2px solid #af2222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 4px 6px 2px
}

section.bmform .btn.btn-danger.minus,
section.bmform .btn.btn-danger.plus {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 2px solid #af2222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 4px 6px 2px
}

section.bmform .bmform-submit-container .bmform_submit:hover,
section.bmform .btn.btn-danger.minus:hover,
section.bmform .btn.btn-danger.plus:hover,
section.bmform .thanks-for-requesting .change-request:hover {
    border: 2px solid #8c2828;
    background-color: #bf0808
}
```

This is the code I'd ideally wish to generate.

```css
section.bmform .thanks-for-requesting .change-request,
section.bmform .bmform-submit-container .bmform_submit,
section.bmform .btn.btn-danger.plus,
section.bmform .btn.btn-danger.minus {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #af2222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 4px 6px 2px 6px;
}
section.bmform .thanks-for-requesting .change-request:hover,
section.bmform .bmform-submit-container .bmform_submit:hover,
section.bmform .btn.btn-danger.plus:hover,
section.bmform .btn.btn-danger.minus:hover {
    border: 2px solid #8c2828;
    background-color: #bf0808;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to use extend. By using extend it groups selectors that share the same style-rules, resulting in more compact code.

Instead of the selectors listed pulling the code from .highlight_bordered in it, it adds its own selector criteria to the `.highlight_bordered` style rules.

```
section.bmform {
    .thanks-for-requesting {
        .change-request {
            &:extend(.highlight_bordered);
        }
    }
    .bmform-submit-container {
        .bmform_submit {
            &:extend(.highlight_bordered);
        }
    }
    .btn {
        &.btn-danger {
            &.plus, 
            &.minus {
                &:extend(.highlight_bordered);
            }
        }
    }
}
```